# Can we generate Contents.m by commands?

Tags: matlab

[Contents.m](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-help-summary-contents-m.html) can be generated by the report feature from UI. Can we create or update it by using commands?

Comment: Did you read http://blogs.mathworks.com/community/2009/01/26/your-table-of-contents/ (Specifically the comments)? Hint `makecontentsfile`.

Comment: @Jørgen The link still uses the report->contents way to generate Contents.m. I think what it does it checks all files in the current folder, extract the first line of each file's comments, and writes to Contents.m. But the link does not say how to to so by a command line API, so we cannot create Contents.m w/o MATLAB UI.

Comment: Its mentioned in the comments, try `help makecontentsfile` from the Command Window.